# RN- How to show loader icon on screen until image is loaded?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to React native. Pictures change when the previous and next buttons are pressed in the application. But it waits for a while until the pictures are loaded onto the screen. Because the images are coming from firebase storage. When the button is pressed, I want a loading icon to appear until the images are loaded. I don't know how to use ActivityIndicator in this situation. Can anybody help me for that?

Application image:

[image]

Codes:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'


const data = [
    { url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/asdsa-69cc0.appspot.com/o/1.jpg?alt=media&token=52de8fce-553d-436d-839e-cc3ee0ec29eb" },
    { url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/asdsa-69cc0.appspot.com/o/2.jpg?alt=media&token=0fa85f40-f134-4010-b575-63c1c82e9c81" }
]

const WordPage = () => {

    const [picture, setPicture] = useState(data[0].url)

    const nextWord = () => {
        setPicture(data[1].url)
    }

    const previousWord = () => {
        setPicture(data[0].url)
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={{ uri: picture }}
                style={styles.image}
            />
            <View style={styles.change}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={previousWord}>
                    <Text>
                        Previous
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={nextWord}>
                    <Text>
                        Next
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default WordPage

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    image: {
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        borderRadius: 10,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        marginTop: 20
    },
    change: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        marginTop: 20,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    }
});
```

I could not apply what is written on this page : [How do I conditionally render a spinner while waiting for a new image to load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752241/how-do-i-conditionally-render-a-spinner-while-waiting-for-a-new-image-to-load)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I conditionally render a spinner while waiting for a new image to load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752241/how-do-i-conditionally-render-a-spinner-while-waiting-for-a-new-image-to-load)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while loading images from a URL we can make use of the props available for Image components. Props like [onLoadStart](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#onloadstart) can be used to set a state variable to show an ActivityIndicator while image loading is started and props like [onLoad](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#onload) or [onLoadEnd](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#onloadend) can be used to change the value of the state variable to hide the ActivityIndicator once the loading is done.

Comment: Your answer will be solve my problem but when I try I see an "Too many re-renders.." error. Can you give an example on my codes?